# Having difficulty looping through JSONP data

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I have the following script, which only seems to get the value from the first iteration of the loop, and not the rest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_jsonp_feed();

    function get_jsonp_feed() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=%20SELECT%20*%20FROM%20html%20WHERE%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fnews.bbc.co.uk%2Fweather%2Fforecast%2F4276%3Fsearch%3Dgerrards%2520cross%26itemsPerPage%3D10%26region%3Dworld%26area%3DGerrards%2520Cross%22%20and%20xpath%20%3D%20'%2F%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=cbfunc",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                var itemList = data.query.results.tr[0].td;

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    alert(itemList[i].div.abbr.content);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This displays `Mon` after which it displays `Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`.  It should be displaying 5 alerts, `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, `Thu`, and `Fri`.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DsEGT/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to be looping through the `tr` elements, not the `td` elements. Make the `success` callback:

```
            var itemList = data.query.results.tr;

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                alert(itemList[i].td[0].div.abbr.content);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer:                 var itemList = data.query.results.tr;

                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    //alert(itemList[i].id);

                    for (var j = 0; j < 5; i++) {
                        var itemList = data.query.results.tr[i].td;
                        
                        alert(itemList[j].div.abbr.content);
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping through the days and get the first property of each day, not looping the properties in the first day:

```
var itemList = data.query.results.tr;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  alert(itemList[i].td[0].div.abbr.content);
}
```